# libcurl: curl_easy_perform blocks unless CURLOPT_READFUNCTION is set

Tags: c++, rest, http, libcurl

I am trying to use libcurl C++ to make REST/HTTP requests. I noticed curl_easy_perform blocks but if I set CURLOPT_READFUNCTION it doesn't. I just want to understand why that is, I am new to libcurl or HTTP/REST protocol.

Here is the code:

```
m_pCurl = curl_easy_init();
curl_easy_setopt(m_pCurl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://blahblahblah/api/auth/user/login");      
curl_easy_setopt(m_pCurl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);
curl_easy_setopt(m_pCurl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_easy_setopt(m_pCurl, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "SKEY=BLAHBLAHBLAH");

struct curl_slist *list = NULL;

list = curl_slist_append(list, "Accept: application/json");
list = curl_slist_append(list, "Connection: keep-alive");
list = curl_slist_append(list, "Expect:");
list = curl_slist_append(list, "Content-Type: application/json");
list = curl_slist_append(list, "x-website-parameters: LALALALA");
curl_easy_setopt(m_pCurl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, list);

// Callbacks
readarg_t rarg;

// readcb is a callback function
// Removing the two lines below will cause curl_easy_perform to hang
curl_easy_setopt(m_pCurl, CURLOPT_READFUNCTION, readcb);
curl_easy_setopt(m_pCurl, CURLOPT_READDATA, &rarg);

CURLcode res = curl_easy_perform(m_pCurl);
```

Note: Some of the encoded data are changed above.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [The Manual](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_READFUNCTION.html)...

> **CURLOPT_READFUNCTION explained**
>
> ...
>
> If you set this callback pointer to NULL, or don't set it at all, the default internal read function will be used. It is doing an fread() on the FILE * userdata set with CURLOPT_READDATA.

However you also don't set `CURLOPT_READDATA`. So looking again at [The manual](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_READDATA.html)...

> **CURLOPT_READDATA explained**
>
> ...
>
> By default, this is a FILE * to stdin.

So the reason your program "hangs" appears to be because it is waiting for something to arrive on the *standard input* `stdin`.

So the way it is supposed to work is this.

**1)** If you do *nothing* the data sent to the server comes from the *standard input* (which is often the keyboard).

**2)** If you set **only** `CURLOPT_READDATA` then it **must** be a `FILE*` you opened to an input file that contains the data you want to send.

**3)** If you set `CURLOPT_READFUNCTION` then `CURLOPT_READDATA` can point to anything **your function** needs to fulfil its task of sending data to the server.

Comment: Thanks for your reply guys, I am not understanding the relations between CURLOPT_READFUNCTION and CURLOPT_READDATA. Like I said before, the above code DID give me a response of the POST request in the callback function readcb. It only hangs when I remove the two lines curl_easy_setopt(m_pCurl, CURLOPT_READFUNCTION, readcb);
curl_easy_setopt(m_pCurl, CURLOPT_READDATA, &rarg);

Comment: If I have CURLOPT_READFUNCTION set, does that mean I don't need CURLOPT_READDATA?

Comment: @KelvinPoon Sorry I missed that you removed **both** lines in order to get it to hang. I have changed the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks! What if I don't need to send any data? i.e. all the information is already in the POST HTTP header. Instead of setting them to NULL and wait for input from stdin, is there a way we can simply skip the data reading?

Comment: @KelvinPoon HTTP POST is for sending data. Maybe you need a GET or a HEAD instead? Otherwise just send zero data.

Comment: The server I am speaking to require a POST but data is in the header only in a form of "x-blah-parameters: data". So it doesn't require a body. I think I finally got it to work, instead of using READDATA I set CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE to 0 and CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS to empty and it worked (The Post was a simple login request)